# Mannekin Pis A copying Stonehenge B

Tags: 7-wonders

We've had a disagreement on how to determine what color card to score when Mannekin Pis A stage 2/3 copies Stonehenge B's stage 2.

*Rulebook on Stonehenge:*

> Stage 2: At the end of the game, the player flips face-up the card used to build this Stage. Then, the player scores 1 victory point for each card of that color pre-sent in both neighboring cities

*Rulebook on Mannekin Pis:*

> Stage 3: The player applies the effect of the last Stage of the Wonder board to their left.

**Does the Mannekin Pis player use the color of their own tucked card, or the color of card the Stonehenge player tucked?**

Our assumption was that it was Mannekin Pis' tucked card. After all, MP does not require the neighbor's stage to have been built, so the other interpretation could lead to a poorly-defined state where there is no card to reference. However, "applies the effect" was vague enough that we weren't completely sure.

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer now, but it'll be MP's own tucked card. MP basically clones the ability, and the SH ability cares about the card used to play it.

Comment: Just wondering, since I haven't got the expansion: is the wonder's name spelled the wrong way in the game as well? Both the question and answer consistently spell it with an i instead of an e.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mannekin Pis uses its own tucked card.

The ability copies the effect of the wonder to their left.  This essentially means it gains the text of the other wonder stage.  That text is: "At the end of the game, the player flips face-up the card used to build this Stage. Then, the player scores 1 victory point for each card of that color present in both neighboring cities."  Reading this text in the context of Mannekin Pis' 3rd stage, "this Stage" refers to  Mannekin Pis' stage 3.

Support for this comes from the rules for the expansion:

> The stages of the targeted Wonder do not need to have been completed by their respecitve ownes for the Menneken Pis to copy them.

For this to be true, the Mannekin Pis must copy the text of the ability rather than copy any of the properties of the other player's wonder board (including what card the other player did or did not use to build that stage of their wonder).

Comment: Your core argument is that "applies the effect" is equivalent to "gains the text". I agree that this basically HAS to be the right interpretation, but I'm not positive I could convince an aggressive rules lawyer of it (who might argue that "applies the effect" means "gains the _result_"). Thankfully we didn't have any of those in our group!

EDIT: I suppose a counterargument to gaining the "result" is -- why wouldn't that include determining who the neighbors are for the power. I'm really just vastly overthinking this and arguing against a nonexistent opponent. ;)

Comment: @tdhsmith I've added support from the rules.  It's not as explicit as I'd like, but it's something to fend off the rules lawyers